# Is there a default template file for child pages / subpages?

Tags: pages, page-template, child-pages, template-hierarchy

This seems like a very simple question.  I'm looking for something like sub-page.php or page-child.php where I can do some different things on the child pages of my theme.

They are different enough in design and content that I'm having to use a lot of php or the CSS .page-child class to do all the dirty work.  I'm looking for a simpler method.

One caveat - I would like this to happen automatically so I don't have to tell the client "make sure to always select the 'subpage' template when you create a subpage!" which is precarious..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no specifica template for child pages, but you can do this pretty easily with the [get_template_part()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) function.

First create a file called "content-child.php".

Second create a file called "content.php".

Next, inside of page.php, place this:

```
if( $post->post_parent !== 0 ) {
    get_template_part('content', 'child');
} else {
    get_template_part('content');
}
```

Anything that you want displayed on a child page will be placed inside of content-child.php. Anything you want displayed on non-child pages will be placed in content.php.

Comment: I was able to make this code work.  As it turned out - I didn't need to separate it quite as much as I thought, so I just adjusted your code and used it in page.php in a couple specific instances.  The CSS selector 'page-child' helped round out the edges.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Great solution. How to set a different template for Parent > Child > Child?
Thanks!

Comment: Same question as Brightweb...

Answer (score 15):

It's actually very easy, add follow code to your `functions.php`

```
add_filter(
    'page_template',
    function ($template) {
        global $post;

        if ($post->post_parent) {

            // get top level parent page
            $parent = get_post(
               reset(array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID)))
            );

            // or ...
            // when you need closest parent post instead
            // $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);

            $child_template = locate_template(
                [
                    $parent->post_name . '/page-' . $post->post_name . '.php',
                    $parent->post_name . '/page-' . $post->ID . '.php',
                    $parent->post_name . '/page.php',
                ]
            );

            if ($child_template) return $child_template;
        }
        return $template;
    }
);
```

Then you can prepare templates with following patterns:

- `[parent-page-slug]/page.php`
- `[parent-page-slug]/page-[child-page-slug].php`
- `[parent-page-slug]/page-[child-post-id].php`

Comment: This is a highly underrated reply, it's way more versatile than the accepted answer. +1 from me and another +1 for using an anonymous function.

Comment: Would this work with parent > child > child of child relationships, and if so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My modification of OzzyCzech's solution above. This function looks in the theme's root directory for files who's name contains the parent's slug or parent's ID.

- `/theme_root/child-PARENT_SLUG.php`
- `/theme_root/child-PARENT_ID.php`

```
function child_templates($template) {
    global $post;

    if ($post->post_parent) {
        // get top level parent page
        $parent = get_post(
            reset(array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID)))
        );

        // find the child template based on parent's slug or ID
        $child_template = locate_template(
            [
                'child-' . $parent->post_name . '.php',
                'child-' . $parent->ID . '.php',
                'child.php',
            ]
        );

        if ($child_template) return $child_template;
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'page_template', 'child_templates' );
```

Comment: Hi - Would this work with parent > child > child of child relationships, and if so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have assigned a specific template to a child page using [Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

I have this root: `localhost:8001/my-custom-post-type/page-one/page-one-sub-child`

Create a template page how in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).

In my case is in a file `page_panoramica.php` i wrote:

```
<?php /* 
  * Template Name: Page Panoramica
  * Template Post Type: my-custom-post-type
*/ ?>
```

After assign the template to the page you need

[image]