# Automatically use specific template to load subpages

Tags: templates

I have a page called Joinery and when open some new pages where I set that their parent is Joinery (under Page attributes), I would like to set Wordpress to automatically use file page-joinery-subpages.php for displaying them without manually selecting template.

My solution is based on this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/218817/85304 ,

```
function load_usetemplate(){
    global $post;
    // get top level parent page
    $parent = get_post(reset(array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID))));

    if($parent->ID === pll__(8)  && !is_page(pll_get_post(8)){
        if ($child_template = locate_template( 'page-joinery-subpages.php')) 
            return $child_template;
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'page_template', 'load_usetemplate' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before getting the top level parent page, you could check if the page has parents; also you forget to define `$template`.

This code should work:

```
function load_usetemplate( $template ){

    global $post;

    if( $post->post_parent > 0 ) {

      // get top level parent page
      $parent = get_post( reset( array_reverse( get_post_ancestors( $post->ID ) ) ) );

      if( $parent->ID === pll__(8) ){
        if ( $child_template = locate_template( 'page-joinery-subpages.php') ) 
            return $child_template;
      }

    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'page_template', 'load_usetemplate' );
```